# not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header

Tags: web-services, authentication, post, oauth, postman

While hitting an API from Postman I am getting this error.

### API details:

#### URL:

https://account-perf.myglobal.com/v1/users/00uk0khprrME7gZOU0h7/credentials/change_password

#### Header:

> Content-Type:application/json
>  Authorization:Bearer
> n7mbkw74jsubd7rauhptdnre

### Type:

*POST*

### Body:

```
{"password":"Baddy125@","token":"eyJhbGci...."}
```

---

### Edit 1:

Web-service call to generate token-

### URL-

https://api-perf.myglobal.com/rest/oauth2/v1/token

### Type-

*POST*

### Body-

> client_id:abcd
>  client_secret:xyz
>  grant_type:client_credentials

Comment: `n7mbkw74jsubd7rauhptdnre` how did you generate this value?

Answer (score 7):

I had this whenever any unhandled endpoint method or resource was called. My setup is an API Gateway with defined resources (e.g. `/myendpoint`) and defined methods for those endpoints (e.g. `GET`).

To fix it, I created a Node.js Lambda function that just returned a 404. Then I added any `ANY` method at the root of the endpoints `/` and pointed it as a Lambda proxy function to the ANY methods.

Then I added a proxy resource, e.g. `/{proxy}` -- there's a checkbox you can click when creating a resource to tell it to proxy. An `ANY` method on that resource pointing to the same Lambda function, deploy the API, and I'm done.

Now instead of the auth bearer token error, I get a proper `HTTP 404` error.

Answer (score 5):

@Matt H - That's pretty good idea this gave me an inspiration of another one.

Assuming all of the other paths within the API are explicitly specified, I created a default path /{proxy+} which would return a http 404, message resource not found. Instead of using lambda, I was able to create a mock response, so there isn't even any cost incurred for getting Lambda to return the response.

I created my APIs via Open API spec. This is how my YAML for the implementation would like

```
  /{proxy+}:
    x-amazon-apigateway-any-method:
      responses:
        404:
          description: "404 response"
          content: {}
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          404:
            statusCode: "404"
            responseTemplates:
              application/json: "{\"message\":\"resource not available\"}"
        requestTemplates:
          application/json: "{\"statusCode\": 404}"
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_templates"
        type: "mock"
```

Serverless also has the ability to specify inline mock response. Below can be a sample:

```
functions:
  default:
    handler: handler.default
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          cors: true
          method: get
          integration: mock
          request:
            template:
              application/json: '{"statusCode": 404}'
          response:
            template: $input.path('$')
            statusCodes:
              404:
                pattern: '' #default method
                template:
                  application/json: '{"statusCode": 404, "message":"resource not found"}'
```

serverless doc: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#custom-response-templates

Answer (score 1):

Analyze and validate the request path, in case the request is incorrect this error is thrown at API Gateway. I stepped on the same error, when corrected the request parameters it worked well.

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by proxying the `ANY /{proxy+}` route to a lambda which will always respond with an HTTP 404

Since all other routes are precisely configured, this `ANY /{proxy+}` route acts as the default one and will catch any unmatched request

Here is how I did it with CloudFormation :

```
Parameters:
    RestAPI:
        Type: String
    RestApiRootResourceId:
        Type: String
    LambdaName:
        Type: String
    Path:
        Type: String

RootResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref RestAPI
      ParentId: !Ref RestApiRootResourceId
      PathPart: !Ref Path
ProxyResource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref RestAPI
      ParentId: !Ref RestApiRootResourceId
      PathPart: "{proxy+}"
AnyMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref RestAPI
    ResourceId: !Ref ProxyResource
    HttpMethod: ANY
    Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        Uri:
          Fn::Join:
            - ":"
            - - !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda"
              - !Sub "path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function"
              - !Sub "${LambdaName}/invocations"
ApiGatewayInvokeLambdaPermissionAny:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName:
        Fn::Join:
          - ":"
          - - !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function"
            - !Ref LambdaName
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn:
        Fn::Join:
          - ":"
          - - !Sub "arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}"
            - !Sub "${RestAPI}/*/ANY/*"
```

Paramters :

- RestAPI is your API ID
- RestApiRootResourceId is the ID of the root resource (`!GetAtt "RestApi.RootResourceId"`)
- LambdaName is the name of your proxy lambda
- Path is something I have bewteen the stage and the root (for mty specific usage)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to define a mapping template to override an API's request and response parameters and status codes [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html). If the goal is simply to improve error handling in API Gateway for unsupported paths, this approach has the advantage of being fairly straightforward and does not have any associated costs (such as invoking a Lambda Function to provide this same facility).

**Example configuration and behavior:**

*https://example.com/*

- There is a base path mapping defined in API GW for this domain.
- But there are no API GW integrations defined for this path.
- When making requests against this path, API GW returns a 403 and some (fairly unintelligible) text that includes the following: `not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header`.

*[https://example.com/taco-recipes/{proxy+}](https://example.com/taco-recipes/%7Bproxy+%7D)*

- This path part inherits from the base path mapping defined in *https://example.com/*.
- This path part has an API Gateway Lambda integration defined.
- Requests that include this path part invoke the integrated Lambda Function and get routed appropriately in the application code.

**Desired behavior:**

- API clients make requests to the undefined paths *https://example.com/burrito-recipes/* or  *https://example.com/*, etc. and receive a more friendly and helpful response.

**Recommendation:**

A very simple example solution (for readers who define API Gateway Integrations in OpenAPI spec) adapted from [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-responses-in-swagger.html).

```yaml
x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
    DEFAULT_4XX:
      statusCode: 404
      pattern: ''
      responseTemplates:
        application/json: '{"message": "My custom error message"}'
```

*NOTE:* One gotcha (context available [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/7892#issuecomment-651682840)) to be aware of is that the `pattern` property *is* required for the template to get picked up by API GW in actual requests.

AWS defines API Gateway default responses [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/7892#issuecomment-651682840). Each of the listed responses may have overrides templates attached using the approach defined above.