# AWS API Gateway: Handle both invalid URL and validation errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API gateway set up with an OpenAPI specification and a proxy lambda integration. Request validation is enabled, and also an authorizer lambda.
Let's say I have endpoints `GET /foo` and `POST /bar`. The integrations to these endpoints work well, and the requests are validated and authenticated.

The problem is this:

In order to send back any validation errors when an *invalid* request is made, e.g. with a missing request body property, I have the following response mapping:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses: 
  BAD_REQUEST_BODY:
    statusCode: 400
    responseTemplates:
      application/json: |
        {"message": "Invalid request body: $context.error.validationErrorString"}
```

This also works well. However, if I try to call an endpoint that doesn't *exist* (e.g. `GET /baz`), I get a very weird default error message from API gateway. From the past I remember getting a HTTP 403 with something like "missing API key" for invalid URLs, which is weird since it should render a 404, but now I get the even stranger body:

```
{
  "message": "'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI <rest of JWT ...>' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI <...>"
}
```

In other words, the JWT I send as my bearer token is passed back in an error message, saying it's not a key=value pair.

Thing is, my authorizer lambda is only connected to the valid endpoints (obviously), so it's not being called. But why is the default built-in API gateway route handler parsing my bearer token and deciding it's not a key=value pair (!)? For an endpoint that doesn't exist? I don't have any `{proxy+}` endpoint at all.

If I try to map all 403 responses (`MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN`, `INVALID_SIGNATURE`, etc) to custom error messages, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-responses-in-swagger.html), I get no result, despite docs saying the default response for missing URLs is `MISSING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN`. However, if I also override `DEFAULT_4XX`, it works, I can return a HTTP 404 with a "Not found" message. The problem is that as soon as I override `DEFAULT_4XX`, it also overrides my `BAD_REQUEST_BODY` response so that my validation error messages are lost. Apparently `DEFAULT_4XX` is not matched last, it takes precedence over `BAD_REQUEST_BODY`!

How can I set up API gateway so that I at the same time can:

- Return 404 NOT FOUND for invalid endpoints such as `GET /baz`
- Return 400 with the `$context.error.validationErrorString` variable for requests that failed validation

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396534/api-gateway-responds-with-403-instead-of-404) that described a similar problem, but surely it's not required to create a `{proxy+}` integration and/or a dedicated separate lambda only to return a 404 error, this must be possible to achieve by configuration!?

Answer (score 0):

I used the openAPI mock proxy (no lambda) solutions documented here: [not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428711/not-a-valid-key-value-pair-missing-equal-sign-in-authorization-header/61549331#61549331)

It is working very well.